# How to inject List<String> in mybatis and INSERT into seperate rows in database?

Tags: list, insert, mybatis

I want to know how to pass List in myBatis configuration and to be inserted in the databse according to the details.

A user post a form with following details where address can be added number of times therefore address is a list. 
When the database is posted, I want the database to insert deatils of the users in seperate rows (could use loop in INSERT statement {but do not know how}).

details.java
private int id
private String name
private String address
private List children

Attempt 1

```
detailsMapper.xml
<resultMap id="details" type="Details">
<result property="id" column="ID"/>
<result property="name" column="NAME"/>
<result property="address" column="ADDRESS"/>
<result property="children" column="CHILDREN" javaType="java.lang.List"/>
</resultMap>
```

Error-> cannot set value for children

Attempt 2

```
<resultMap id="detailMapper" type="String">
<result property="children" column="CHILDREN" javaType="java.lang.List"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="details" type="Details">
<result property="id" column="ID"/>
<result property="name" column="NAME"/>
<result property="address" column="ADDRESS"/>
<collection property="children" resultMap="detailMapper"/>
</resultMap>
```

Error -> Argument mixmatch, cannot set property

```
<insert id="submitDetails" parameterType="Details">
INSERT INTO USER_DETAILS (NAME, ADDRESS, CHILDREN)
VALUES(
#{name, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
#{address, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
#{children, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
)
</insert>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following syntax to do that:

```
<insert id="submitDetails" parameterType="java.util.List">
INSERT INTO USER_DETAILS (NAME, ADDRESS, CHILDREN)
VALUES 
   <foreach item="item" collection="list" separator=",">
     (#{item.name}, #{item.address}, #{item.children})
  </foreach>
</insert>
```

You have a list of Details so `parameterType` should be `java.util.List`.

Further reading: [Mybatis batch insert](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html)

Comment: Hi thank you. Do you know how to inject List<String> or String[] in mybatis?

Comment: @JohnSmith, you can use the same syntax for all the types of `List`.

Comment: @JohnSmith I can see that, you have mentioned `java.lang.List` in mapper configuration. All the collection classes including List class is under `java.util` package.

Comment: When I set javaType="java.util.List" then it says, No typehandler found

Comment: You should be using an object that is not a `java.util.List` thats why you get that exception.